# Error in displaying the image of the screenshot of a webpage

Tags: php, webpage-screenshot

I've the code which takes the screen shot of the specified div tab. But I'm encountering the problem to display it as .png file from base64 format

Here is my code. 
It has two separate files

1) Download.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>
<!-- -->
<div id="target">
<img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="100" height="100">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function capture() {
        $('#target').html2canvas({
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
            $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            //Submit the form manually
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    });
}
 </script>
<input type="submit" value="Take Screenshot Of Div" onclick="return capture();" />
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" id="myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
```

2)Save.php

```
    <?php
//Show the image
$data = $_POST['img_val'];

//Get the base-64 string from data
$uri = substr($data, strpos($data, ",") + 1);
//Decode the string

$unencodedData = base64_decode($uri);
$im = str_replace($data, '+', 'img.png');
//Save the image
$v = file_put_contents($data, $im);
$result = '<img src="' . $im . '" />';
print_r($result);
?>
```

I need the image to be displayed as localhost/xyz/screenshot/img.png which I'm unable to do.Please see the code help me to figure out that problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var_dump($im);`and paste output here

Comment: after using var_dump($im); I'm getting the output as string(7) "img.png"

Comment: Check my answer is this you want to say ?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any element in `html` with id attribute of `target` in your code but you are using it

```
$('#target').html2canvas({
```

Similar question [here][1]

I have found some thing usefull

```
var html2obj = html2canvas($('body'));

var queue  = html2obj.parse();
var canvas = html2obj.render(queue);
var img = canvas.toDataURL();

window.open(img);
  [1]: http://stac
```

koverflow.com/questions/10457608/create-screenshot-of-webpage-using-html2canvas-unable-to-initialize-properly

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @Moeed still that problem exists as it was. I mean no change has happened

Comment: what is error you are facing ?? you want to show your image ?

Comment: show me the output of 
var_dump($data ); ---- var_dump($uri); ----- var_dump($im);

Comment: output of var_dump($uri): string(29952) "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB3AAAABkCAYAAAB3nKFFAAAgAElEQVR4Xu3dd5xdZb018LX3qdOTSSGVJr0rAlIFBEEEkSYICKKIIuJVr9hQ78UKFixXRAWliQiCNBUpChp6l9AhISQkpJBkJtNO3ftd65nZceASwPcVeTFr8zk5Z87ZZ5fvDH+tz/o9UcoN/+JNp9QjSmuIkEPaKAAxLyONgEIvn8t85BFFEbgn0maDr/VxinqOr/mdCHk0E4TnmB/m+XnCn/XI54dvKE2T8L3hjR+gMfKsWy4gSorcaWRf7RdrrzqPzhdpbuVniJv8sMpHCx8rD/gvVvPpLGABC1jAAhawgAUsYAELWMACFrCABSxgAQtYwAIWsIAFLGCBf3eB6LUMcNFsIooHGNCOQRrXkSYF5qa9jEhbGKEyYFVWGh5KWRXApmgyYI0UsDJmZTzLVwpzlb0mDGyHf13NRIFvjDjWJyNprpLa52XVEb+nz4ePq5Ol4bg6ap3PDJVD"...

Comment: output of var_dump($data): same as var_dump($uri)

Comment: output of var_dump($im):string(7) "img.png"

Comment: I'm using "target" as id for div tab for which I need the screenshot

Comment: I guess problem can be solved if the captured image is stored to server. If that is the case can u please help how to store captured image to server?